# How to model this correctly in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I have a requirement that I am not sure how to accomplish, in my existing data I have a list of customers, each customer should be assigned a staffMember to work with them, so would this be a 1 to 1 relationship or a 1 to many relationship, having trouble wrapping my head around how to model the data, as I want to figure out how to model this correctly. Since a staff member can be assigned to many different customers How should I model this? Does this look correct? 
What I would like is to have the form pull the list of staff members available from the staff table, when inputting a new customer, ideally by the name 
which I figure I could probably do using linq..

```
    public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
    public Staff Staff { get; set; }

    public List<CustomerJob> CustomerJobs { get; set; }

}
       public class Staff
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don’t you just have staff take a list of customers ?

Answer (score 0):

`Customer` have exactly 1 `Staff` while a single `Staff` maybe assigned to more than 1 `Customer`. So this is a **one-to-many** relation.

It is better that `Customer` be aware of its `Staff`. It could be called `AssignedStaff`. `Staff` itslef does not need to have a property to show all its `Csutomers`. Tough you can extract `Customer` list of a `Staff` using a simple query.

My recommended class structure is as follow:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
    public Staff AssignedStaff { get; set; }

    public List<CustomerJob> CustomerJobs { get; set; }
}

public class Staff
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
}
```

A query for extracting `Customer` list of a `Staff`:

```
var customers = _dbContext.Customers.Where(x => x.AssignedStaff.Id == staffId);
```

Comment: Thanks, Ideally though I would like the customers query to return a list of staff names, not by id, I can't think of how to do that though. My goal is to make it easier to add records and id's aren't exactly user friendly

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need a list of staff to show in a drop down box, so any staff could be slected as a `AssignedStaff`. So you need a simple query on `Staff` to extract data based on your criteria, i.e. Name, Phone or EMail.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I want, but since the scaffolded view is strongly typed I am not sure how I can add that to my viewmodel and have it work correctly.

Comment: So that would be a UI issue not an entity-framework. It serves a new question.